# geotools reader

Tags: java, tiff, raster, geotools

I have a problem when I try to get object from  AbstractGridCoverage2DReader. I need it to get CoordinateReferenceSystem and coverage.

```
File file = new File("Resource/new.tif");

AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(file);
System.out.println("here we have format: "+format);

AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(file);
System.out.println("here we have reader: "+reader);
```

Format is ok: "org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat@ed5ad5d".
But reader is always NULL.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it a tiff or a geotiff?

Comment: System.out.println("desc: "+format.getDescription()); gave me: 
"Tagged Image File Format with Geographic information"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved it, change the pom.xml file (i have a maven-based project).

(1):
     
     org.geotools
     gt-epsg-hsql
     ${geotools.version}

(2):
     
     org.geotools
     gt-epsg-hsql
     2.7-M2

I changed (1) on (2) and it works fine! :).

Comment: unless you are using geotools version 2.7-M2 that shouldn't fix it - the most likely underlying reason is probably that maven isn't updating properly.